# Trying to install Ubuntu and got message about Kernels

Tags: kernel

We have a lot of computers that have been donated to our school, but they are all running very slow. I am trying to find a way to make the computers run better without costing us an arm and a leg.

Someone suggested I try Ubuntu and I just tried installing it on one of our old computers. I got the following message:

> This kernel requires an x86-64 CPU, but only detected an i686 CPU. Unable to boot.

Is there an older version that I would be able to install so we can use the computers. I have about 20 computers throughout the school and we have not been able to use very many of them for a few years. We are trying to make them run faster, so we can run some new math and reading software we will be getting in the fall.

Comment: From about 2006 onwards most Intel processors have been 64-bit enabled. Older processors will require you to install the 32-bit version of Ubuntu. (for old computers you might find that Lubuntu runs better on them)

Answer (score 3):

The message you are receiving means that you are trying to install 64-bit software on a 32-bit system.  You have to download the 32-bit version of Ubuntu which can be found over [here](http://releases.ubuntu.com/16.04/) and this is the .iso you need to download: **ubuntu-16.04-desktop-i386.iso**.

Since you are about to use Ubuntu on older machines, it would be better if you gave us more information about their hardware and RAM size because Ubuntu is not a very light distro and it's very likely that you may need a lighter one.